# Understanding `NestList` with multiple functions

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, recursion

## General question

For a function `f[n, a]`, where `a` is a list and `n` is a whole number, what is the correct syntax for

```
f[n - 5, f[n - 4, f[n - 3, f[n - 2, f[n - 1, f[n, a]]]]]]
```

?

## Update

All I want to do is

```
fg[n_, w_] := f1@ff[n, w]
fg[n - 2, fg[n - 1, fg[n, list]]]
```

as shown above, which works, but I am having to manually write out `n-3,n-2,n-1,...`

Have tried

```
fg[n_][w_] := f1@ff[n, w]
NestList[fg[n], list, 3]
```

but doesn't quite work. I think it needs a `#-1` in there somewhere, that is applied to the `n`, but not sure on syntax.

Comment: Wait ... do you need help with `NestList[]` or with _that_ code?

Comment: @martin I'm also having trouble understanding what you're trying to do here..

Comment: @belisarius It is just the last line I need help with - the `fg[n - 2, fg[n - 1, fg[n, list]]]` bit

Comment: @Kris please see update

Comment: Just need another way of writing `fg[n - 2, fg[n - 1, fg[n, list]]]`

Comment: `Nest[fg[#[[1]] - 1, fg @@ ##] &, {n, list}, 2]`

Comment: @belisarius can't get that to work - not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: @martin First ClearAll["Global`*"]

Comment: @belisarius have tried that - is that for `fg[n_][w_] := f1@ff[n, w]` or `fg[n_, w_] := f1@ff[n, w]`?

Comment: @belisarius there might have been a problem with the example code - up[dated so should work now.

Comment: @Kris there might have been a problem with the example code - up[dated so should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Last @ Nest[{ #[[1]] - 1,  f1[ ff[ #[[1]], #[[2]] ] ] } &,
            {n, list}, 
            3]
```

> ```
> f1[ff[-2 + n, f1[ff[-1 + n, f1[ff[n, list]]]]]]
> ```

Comment: Great - thank you - I was really struggling there!

Comment: ok changed as advised :)

Answer (score 4):

Could it be that you're looking for the function `Fold` rather than `Nest`?

```
Fold[f[n - #2, #1] &, a, Range[5]]
```

> ```
> f[-5 + n, f[-4 + n, f[-3 + n, f[-2 + n, f[-1 + n, a]]]]]
> ```

Comment: +1, maybe better `Fold[g[#2, #] &, a, Range[n, n - 2, -1]]`.

Comment: @Kuma Thanks, I agree that a one-liner is nicer. I updated the answer