# Recursive definition of nested functions

Tags: function-construction, recursion

This is probably very easy, but I cannot figure out a way to define a function like:
$$ g_h = ( 1 + f_1(1+f_2(1+f_3(.. (1 + f_h)))))$$

Comment: Look up `Fold[]`.

Comment: @J.M. "easily found in the documentation" ??

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, if you put the word "fold" in somewhere, sure… otherwise no. ;)

Comment: Related: [(7366)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7366/121), [(66021)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66021/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) should work for you:

```
Fold[1 + #2[#1] &, x, Reverse @ {f1, f2, f3, f4}]
```

> ```
> 1 + f1[1 + f2[1 + f3[1 + f4[x]]]]
> ```

Comment: I was about to submit this when your answer showed up.  This gives OP's more exactly I think:  `g[h_] := Fold[1 + Subscript[f, #2][#1] &, 1 + Subscript[f, h], 
  Reverse@Range@(h - 1)]`

Comment: @JasonB If the OP wants to generate this expression for typesetting that will help.  If writing a program I would recommend avoiding subscripts.

Comment: People like their subscripts, who are we to fight?  :-P

Comment: @Mr-Wizard, can you point me to a post on here where it clearly shows the pitfalls of using `Subscript` indiscriminately, in a common situation?  I don't use it myself, but it was years before I figured out that `f[1]` was the right substitute for $f_1$.  Until then, I was doing `ToExpression["f"<>IntegerString[1]]` in my loops, which is cumbersome.

Comment: @JasonB point #3 in [(18395)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/121) is the first thing that comes to mind.  Perhaps there is more.  I simply know that many experienced users have cautioned against this, and early in the process of learning *Mathematica* I had a number of problems which I later traced to the use of subscripts.  As a result I reserve `Subscript` almost entirely for formatting.

Answer (score 3):

So the way to get exactly what is written is

```
g[h_] := Fold[1 + Subscript[f, #2][#1] &, 1 + Subscript[f, h], Reverse@Range@(h - 1)]
```

so that

```
g[5]
```

gives

[image]

But as is pointed out all the time here, you should avoid subscripts.  Anytime you want to use $f_i$, you should use `f[i]` instead.  So in this case what you need is

```
g[h_] := 
 Fold[1 + f[#2][#1] &, 1 + f[h], Reverse@Range@(h - 1)]
g[5]
(* 1 + f[1][1 + f[2][1 + f[3][1 + f[4][1 + f[5]]]]] *)
```

Less readable, but now you don't have to worry about what a `DownValue` of `Subscript` is.